# Responsive HR alignment in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I'd like the HR tag to have the same responsive alignment as the text using Bootstrap 3, so when the text is centered it sits underneath, also centered. And when the text is left aligned, the HR sits underneath, and is also left aligned.

I thought this would be possible by wrapping it in a div alongside the  tag, using text-xs-center and text-lg-left, but the classes only appears to affect the text.

Is there a clever way to acheive this?

Note: I'm using HR and not border-bottom as it has a specific length (60px) which stays the same regardless of the length of the H1 title.

```
<div class="title-block text-xs-center text-lg-left">
  <h1>My Title</h1>
  <hr>
</div>
```

And my Sass;

```
.title-block {
  display: block;
  h1 {
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  hr {
    width: 60px;
    border-top: 1px solid #1c1c1c;
  } 
}
```

Here are pictures of the desired effect;

LEFT aligned;

[image: left aligned]

CENTER aligned

[image: center aligned]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **pseduo element** css you can achieve this. Give **h1** `position:relative` and using `:after` add a line of `width:60px` and giving it `position:absolute` set its position to achieve the desired result **:)**

```css
.title-block {
  display: block;
    text-align:left;
}
.title-block h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 35px;
 position:relative;
  display: inline-block;

}
.title-block h1:after{
content:'';
width:60px; height:1px; background:red; position:absolute; bottom:-5px;
left:0px; right:auto; margin:0px auto;
}

@media(max-width:768px){
.title-block{ text-align:center}
.title-block h1:after{left:0px; right:0px;}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="title-block text-xs-center text-lg-left">
  <h1>My Title</h1>

</div>
```

Comment: yup my answer  ;)

Comment: @dippas i had the same idea.. but you posted answer a minute before while I was editing.. you can take all the credits .. No Problem :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers guys, but I'm using HR as it has a fixed width of 60px.

Comment: @Paddyfields So your width will always be 60px?

Comment: Of the HR, not the title, it just sits underneath

Comment: @paddyfields updated my answer.. Now I am using a fixed width 60px like thing.. the pseudo element to achieve this.. fully responsive and flexible

Comment: Hi, thanks again, but this still doesn't answer my question in the sense that the underline stays in the same place (center aligned). Please have a look at the question I've added a few pictures.

Comment: it will got according to the placement of your h1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143393/discussion-between-sahil-dhir-and-paddyfields).

Answer (score 2):

what about using `border-bottom` in `h1`

**EDIT**

> Hi, thanks but the hr has a specific width of 60px, this just
>   underlines the whole thing. Sorry I should have stated that more
>   clearly

Use pseudo element `::before` or `::after`

```css
.title-block h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.title-block h1::before {
  content: "";
  height: 1px;
  width: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1c1c1c;
}

.title-block.text-xs-center h1::before {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.title-block.text-lg-left h1::before {
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="title-block text-xs-center text-lg-left">
  <h1>My Title</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but the hr has a specific width of 60px, this just underlines the whole thing. Sorry I should have stated that more clearly.

Comment: Thank you, but the question concerns the positioning of the undeline itself. This still keeps it centered. I've added a few screenshots to make it clearer.

Comment: @paddyfields see updated answer. no need for media queries